# Freeing causes crash

Tags: c, malloc

I am currently implementing a pseudocode of Dijkstra's Algorithm and I am having trouble in freeing the nodes. My code seems to be working fine except for the freeing part. I have freed all mallocs in the code but it still keeps on crashing.

I  have checked all possible "mis-free" that might occur and I'm currently stuck with this.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//#####################################################################
//#####################################################################
//#####################################################################

//#####################################################################
//######################### Structures ################################
//#####################################################################

struct node
{
    int vertex;
    int cost;
    struct node* next;
};

struct PQ
{
    int* heap;
    int* index;
    double* key;
    int sizePQ;
};

//#####################################################################
//######################### Graph Things ##############################
//#####################################################################

struct node* createNode(int v,int cost)
{
    struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->vertex = v;
    newNode->cost = cost;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct G{
    int n;
    int* pred;
    double* dist;
    struct node** LIST;
};

struct G* initGraph(int vertices)
{
    struct G* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct G));
    graph->n = vertices-1;

    graph->LIST = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));
    graph->pred = malloc(vertices * sizeof(int));
    graph->dist = malloc(vertices * sizeof(double));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= vertices; i++)
        graph->LIST[i] = NULL;

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct G* graph, int src, int dest, int cost)
{
    struct node* newNode = createNode(dest, cost);
    newNode->next = graph->LIST[src];
    graph->LIST[src] = newNode;
}

void freeG(struct G* graph){
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v <= graph->n+1; v++)
    {
        struct node* temp = graph->LIST[v];
        struct node* temp2 = temp->next;
        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            free(temp);
            temp = temp2;
            temp2 = temp->next;
        }
    }
    free(graph->pred);
    free(graph->dist);
    free(graph->LIST);
    free(graph);
}

void freePQ(struct PQ* PQ){
    free(PQ->heap);
    free(PQ->key);
    free(PQ->index);
    free(PQ);
}
//#####################################################################
//############################ Procedures #############################
//#####################################################################

void PQ_UNDERFLOW(){
    printf("Underflow Detected");
}

void InitPQ(struct G* G,struct PQ* PQ, int s){
    PQ->heap = malloc(G->n * sizeof(int));
    PQ->index = malloc(G->n * sizeof(int));
    PQ->key = malloc(G->n * sizeof(double));
    PQ->sizePQ = G->n;
   // printf("%i",G->n);

    int i = 1;
    int v;
    for(v=1;v<=G->n;v++){
        if(v==s){
            PQ->heap[1]=s;
            PQ->index[s]=1;
            PQ->key[s]=0;
        }
        else{
            ++i;
            PQ->heap[i]=v;
            PQ->index[v]=i;
            PQ->key[v]=INFINITY;
           // printf("%i//",PQ->heap[i]);
            //printf("%lf ",PQ->key[v]);
        }
    }
}

void HEAPIFY(struct PQ* PQ,int r){
    //printf("%i",PQ->heap[r]-1);
    double k = PQ->key[PQ->heap[r]];
    int l = PQ->heap[r];
    int i = r, j = 2*i;
    while(j<=PQ->sizePQ){
        if (j<PQ->sizePQ && PQ->key[PQ->heap[j+1]]< PQ->key[PQ->heap[j]]){
            ++j;
        }
        if(PQ->key[PQ->heap[j]]<k){
            PQ->heap[i]=PQ->heap[j];
            PQ->index[PQ->heap[j]]=i;
            i=j;
            j=2*i;
        }else break;
    }
    PQ->heap[i]=l;
    PQ->index[l]=i;
}

int IsEmptyPQ(struct PQ* PQ){
    return(PQ->sizePQ==0);
}

void EXTRACT_MIN(struct PQ* PQ, int *j){

    if (PQ->sizePQ == 0) PQ_UNDERFLOW();
    else{
        *j=PQ->heap[1];
        PQ->heap[1] = PQ->heap[PQ->sizePQ];
        PQ->index[PQ->heap[1]]=1;
        PQ->sizePQ=PQ->sizePQ-1;
        HEAPIFY(PQ,1);
    }
}

void DECREASE_KEY(struct PQ* PQ, int l, double newkey){
    PQ->key[l] = newkey;
    int i = PQ->index[l];//printf("pqindexl->%i\n",PQ->index[l]);
    int j =floor(i/2);
    while (i > 1 && PQ->key[PQ->heap[j]]>newkey){
        PQ->heap[i]= PQ->heap[j];
        PQ->index[PQ->heap[j]]=i;
        i=j; j =floor(i/2);
    }
    PQ->heap[i]=l;
    PQ->index[l]=i;
}
//#####################################################################
//############################ DIJKSTRA   #############################
//#####################################################################

void DIJKSTRA(struct G* G, struct PQ* PQ, int s){
    InitPQ(G,PQ,s);
    int u = 0,v;
    double newval;
    G->pred[s]=0;
    while(!IsEmptyPQ(PQ)){
        EXTRACT_MIN(PQ,&u);
        if (PQ->key[u]== INFINITY){break;}
        struct node* a = G->LIST[u];
        while (a!=NULL)
        {
            v = a->vertex;//printf("vertex = %i\n",a->vertex);
            newval = PQ->key[u]+a->cost;
            if (PQ->key[v]>newval){
                G->pred[v]=u;
                DECREASE_KEY(PQ,v,newval);
            }
            a = a->next;
        }
    }
    G->dist=PQ->key;
}


//#####################################################################
//############################  print g   #############################
//#####################################################################

void DISPLAY_PATH(struct G* G, int s,int v){
    int path[G->n];
    int len = 1;
    path[len]=v;
    int i=v;
    while(i!=s){
        if(G->pred[i]==0){printf("No path found");return;}
        else{
            i = G->pred[i];
            ++len;
            path[len]=i;
        }
    }
    printf("Shortest path found: ");
    while(len>=1){
        printf("%i",path[len]);
        if(len!=1)printf(" -> ");
        len--;
    }
}

void printGraph(struct G* graph)
{
    int v;
    for (v = 1; v <= graph->n; v++)
    {
        struct node* temp = graph->LIST[v];
        printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n ", v);
        while (temp)
        {
            printf("%d -> ", temp->vertex);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
//#####################################################################
//#####################################################################
//#####################################################################
int main()
{
    struct G* graph = initGraph(10);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 8, 8);
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3, 8);
    addEdge(graph, 2, 8, 11);
    addEdge(graph, 3, 4, 7);
    addEdge(graph, 3, 9, 2);
    addEdge(graph, 3, 6, 4);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 5, 9);
    addEdge(graph, 4, 6, 14);
    addEdge(graph, 5, 6, 10);
    addEdge(graph, 6, 7, 2);
    addEdge(graph, 7, 8, 1);
    addEdge(graph, 7, 9, 6);
    addEdge(graph, 8, 9, 7);
    printGraph(graph);
    printf("\n");

    struct PQ* PQ=malloc(sizeof(struct PQ));
    DIJKSTRA(graph, PQ, 1);
    DISPLAY_PATH(graph,1,8);

    freePQ(PQ);
    freeG(graph);
}
```

Everything works fine except for the freeing part. It prints the desired output for the algorithm but crashes at the end of the program.

I also really want to understand how malloc and freeing works and this might give me more information about it.

[Here's what happens everytime I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqdo8.png)

EDIT: I have ran valgrind on my code and it appears to get an error called "core dumped". As far as i know, core dumped error occurs when I freed a node twice or more. I don't see any errors in my freeing codes though.

[Here is what valgrind outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP0uR.png)

Comment: "Pretty" comments like that are are worse than useless. They're hard to maintain if they need to be changed, and content such as "structures" and "graph things" conveys no information beyond the already-blatantly obvious as to what the code is doing and why.

Comment: I use those comments to help me find procedures and functions easier in long codes. It really helps me a lot.

Comment: Run it with the debugger. Visual Studio has a very easy to use debugger.

Comment: Learn about [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: Valgrind should have said a lot more than just "core dumped".  Before that happened it should have printed information on invalid reads / writes or something similar.  Post the output of valgrind so we can see what really happened.

Comment: I've edited the post. I attached a picture of what valgrind outputs.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using Valgrind ? If so, are there any errors ?

Valgrind is a tool to check memory leaks and memory violation. It replaces your system malloc by its own to observe your actions.

Also please avoid using UPPERCASE functions, these should be reserved for macro and macro functions (`#define`).
You should also use `typedef` to rename your structs.
For example,

```
typedef struct s_myStruct
{
  ...
} t_myStruct;

t_mystruct *st = malloc(sizeof(t_mystruct));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems wrong:

```
for (v = 0; v <= graph->n+1; v++)
{
    struct node* temp = graph->LIST[v];
```

As `n` is initialized to `9` in `initGraph` this code will loop for v = 0, 1, ..., 10

However, in `initGraph` you malloc'ed 10 elements so now you access `LIST` out of bounds.

Try

```
for (v = 0; v < graph->n+1; v++)
{
    struct node* temp = graph->LIST[v];
```

instead.

Then look at this:

```
    struct node* temp = graph->LIST[v];
    struct node* temp2 = temp->next;
```

What would happen if `graph->LIST[v]` is NULL?

The program will crash when you do:

```
temp2 = temp->next
```

So you need to turn the code into something like:

```
    struct node* temp = graph->LIST[v];
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        struct node* temp2 = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = temp2;
    }
```

Comment: Changed it that way..  Still crashes :( but i think it solved one problem

Comment: It still crashes. I tried adding printf after freePQ(PQ) to check if it passes through freePQ(PQ). It appears that it also crashes at freePQ.

Comment: What if you don't call `DIJKSTRA` and `DISPLAY_PATH` ? Does it still crash?

Comment: Yea it still crashes. It appears that my code is able to free all mallocs but my code seems to be overdoing it.